# Trying to access MdTabBody in Angular Material 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to get access to the origin and position properties of the created MdTabBody objects using:

```
@ViewChildren(MdTabBody) tabbodies: QueryList<MdTabBody>;
```

I want to control how the tab slides into view every time I reload the tabs.

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/NDZSoH0VYnrZLoM5kjWl

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the md-tab-body element defined anywhere in your html. If you want to get the md-tab elements, you should add:

```
import {MdTab} from "@angular/material";
```

and:

```
 @ViewChildren(MdTab) mdtabs: QueryList<MdTab>;
```

Comment: That is true, I don't have md-tab-body elements because they are created dynamically. I still need to access the tab bodies so I can control the way the tabs slide. I don't see a way to get to them from the mdTabs.